# Go Client using WebSocket to connect to NodeJS express/http Server

Tags: node.js, go, websocket

Running a NodeJS express/http server which accepts connections from a NodeJS socket.io-client to send JSON docs for processing.

For example, the below NodeJS client code works sending a JSON doc to the the running NodeJS server:

```
url.href = 'http://localhost:3006/api/dosomething';
var socket = io(url.origin, {
        path: url.pathname,
        reconnection: false
    });
socket.on("start", (send) => {
...
   send(doc);
```

Now, is it possible to use a Go client presumably using WebSocket to perform the above identical action?

With the NodeJS http server running, executed the below Go client just trying to first off dial into the server which resulted in the error message noted at the bottom:

```
import (
    ...
    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
)

func main() {
    origin := "http://localhost/"
    url := "ws://localhost:3006"
    ws, err := websocket.Dial(url, "", origin)
    if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
    }
...
```

Error message:
2021/04/07 21:08:34 websocket.Dial ws://localhost:3006: unexpected EOF
exit status 1

Comment: It's a good idea to switch to one of the websocket packages recommended in the [golang.org/x/net/websocket package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/websocket).   It looks like the Go code and JS code use different paths.